# Calculate Vth in thevenin's circuit

Tags: voltage, resistance, current-source, thevenin

[image]

I want to calculate Vo by Thevenin's theorem. First I removed the RL(1k)

[image]

Now I have to calculate Vth. Can I say that Vth is 6V? or Vth=6V + voltage through 2k?

If both these options are wrong, then tell me any law or procedure to find Vth?

Comment: You already have a question on this topic. If you wanted to change the information, you should have edited your first question.

Comment: That was put on hold, so edit wouldn't help I guess. @DerStrom8

Comment: The laws and procedures are found ***everywhere***, already. The problem is that you don't understand their application. And so you are asking for a long teaching lesson, instead. And that's a big ask. Let me ask you a question. You write, "Can I say that Vth is 6V?" Why would you think so, given all the *stuff* sitting there to the left of the 6 V voltage source? Wouldn't all that stuff there affect what is "seen" by something at the terminals? (And I also want to know why you removed RL. But it is a less important question.)

Comment: while solving circuit using thevenin's theorem, first step is to remove RL, so I did the same. Anyway I didn't ask you for a long teaching lesson, you just simple tell me law or procedure, I will calculate all the values myself. Also is it correct that Vth=6V + voltage through 2k? @jonk

Comment: @Tom editing the question allows members to review the edits and vote to re-open the question. That's how it works. Starting a whole new question will just get it closed.

Comment: Tom, why do you think you need to remove the load resistance if you want to find the Thevenin Resistance to later solve for the Thevenin Voltage?

Comment: @KingDuken I am finding Thevenin voltage right now. can you help me in it?

Comment: I'll give you a quick hint: The dependent current source, \$2I_x\$ contributes to the Thevenin Voltage.

Comment: @Tom There's no reason to remove RL. The fact that you think so is probably more because of your prior experiences and their context. Since we have no clues about that, not having experienced it with you, it's difficult to know how to set you right again. I would not do what you did, in any case.

Comment: ok jonk, starting this left most two components, what we get?

Comment: Since you have a dependent current source, what "device" do you think you need to place to help you calculate for \$V_{TH}\$?

Comment: @KingDuken can we do source transformation in dependent sources? what do you suggest where to start?

Comment: @Tom Yes, you can do the source transformation just fine. You just have a variable in there instead of a constant value, that's all. Nothing new here.

Comment: Can we say that Ix=V/R = 6/2 =3?

Comment: @KingDuken I don't know what device. can you tell?

Comment: @Tom NO YOU CANNOT SAY THAT... Do some circuit analysis. Figure out _what_ the dependent current source \$2I_x\$ _depends on_.

Comment: @Tom Starting at the left I get \$V_{TH}=1\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 2\cdot I_X\$ and \$R_{TH}=1\:\text{k}\Omega\$. From here you have a very, very simple series loop circuit making it absolutely ***trivial*** to compute \$I_X\$. Knowing that you know the output voltage, also trivially reached.

Comment: Dependent source 2Ix depends on current through 2k resistance, Kingduke

Comment: @jonk how Vth=1kΩ ⋅ 2 ⋅ IX ?

Comment: @Tom How do ***you*** convert a Norton to a Thevenin? What steps do you take?

Comment: In Norton theorem, we  find I(nor) , and in thevenin we find Vth

Comment: @tom can you simply tell me the value of Ix? or Vth?

Comment: @Tom No. How do you convert a Norton source pair into a Thevenin source pair? Do you have a procedure for that? If so, what's stopping you from attempting it? If not, then that is a problem I think.

Comment: Tom, @jonk is trying to make sure you understand how to solve these problems for your future. Therefore, he will not tell you the answer but how to get the answer. **Do not ask people for an answer, especially to someone who is trying to make sure you understand it or at least, trying to figure out what you're not understanding.** Asking Jonk for the answer would not only waste his time, it you would impede your understanding of the problem. The purpose of this website is to help you understand how to do something rather than simply giving you an answer.

Comment: And I promise I'm not trying to be rude. But that's just how it is here :)

Comment: Ix is not the same in your two diagrams. Just a simple question: what is the value of Ix in your second diagram, given that it is flowing towards an open circuit?

Comment: @KingDuken, ok I understand now.

Comment: @Chu value of the Ix is not given

Comment: What current flows towards an open circuit? Do you know what an open circuit is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the easiest dependent source questions I can recall.

Just use the usual transformation of a Norton source to a Thevenin source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwFI3a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note the above conversion isn't at all remarkable.

---

Do you follow the Norton source pair to Thevinin source pair conversion above? If so, then isn't this circuit relatively easy now to analyze for \$I_X\$?

If not, then perhaps you aren't prepared yet to answer a question like this?

Or, alternately, perhaps I am not aware of what mental tools you have on hand and therefore cannot know well how to help you use them for this problem?

---

The above circuit folds instantly into the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCyPtCm.png)</sup>

If you cannot solve for \$I_X\$ there, I'm not sure what's left to suggest. (And you should be able to work out the Thevenin resistance and voltage without any significant effort.)

Comment: Oh a big thanks for all this explanation, Now I am getting it

Comment: @Tom Thanks for letting me know it helped. It helps to know that the time helped out and I appreciate that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit is open, therefore you will always read the source voltage (6V).

Basic electronics troubleshooting 101: if you read the source voltage in the circuit, the circuit is open or non conducting from where you are measuring at.