# How to find voltage across the 2k ohm resistor in the given circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have to find Vo in the network given below using Thevenin’s theorem. After removing load resistance i.e. 1k ohm, i know that Ix=V2k/2k but I am stuck on finding voltage across the 2k ohm i.e. V2k. I am familiar with voltage dividers but confused by the current source

[image]

Comment: Didn't we do this one like yesterday?

Comment: if \$2I_x\$ "leave" the current source at the top, and \$1I_x\$ then goes into the 2kΩ (**not** KΩ; what shitty book is this from?), then how much current flows through the left 1 kΩ (**not** K) resistor? Also, this schematic is bad; get something with better notation (for example: named resistors instead of only values) to learn from, this is a disgrace. (A bright, colorful disgrace at that.)

Comment: Why do you want to remove the 1-k\$\Omega\$ resistance? If it is part of the "black box" it should stay in. This one is kinda easy to solve. Apply the recommendations from Monsieur Müller and you should be able to swiftly determine \$I_x\$ which is the voltage across \$R_2\$ divided by \$R_2\$. Then \$I_x\$ flows in the right-side 1-k\$\Omega\$ resistance so you have \$V_{th}\$. The short circuit current (and then \$R_{th}\$) is also easy to derive if you express the new \$I_x\$ while the short circuit is applied.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear circuit and the determination of \$I_x\$ is the first step. The \$2I_x\$ controlled source splits in \$I_x\$ in the 1-k\$\Omega\$ and the 2-k\$\Omega\$ resistors. The current is thus the voltage across the 2-k\$\Omega\$ resistor divided by \$R_2\$. If you do the maths ok, you should get \$I_x=\frac{I_xR_1-(I_xR_3-V_1)}{R_2}\$ with labels as shown in the below sheets. Solving for \$I_x\$ gives \$I_x=\frac{V_1}{R_2-R_1+R_3}=3\;mA\$. As \$I_x\$ circulates in \$R_3\$ also, the Thévenin voltage is simply \$V_{th}=R_3I_x=3\;V\$.

Now, short the 1-k\$\Omega\$ resistance and determine \$I_x\$ once again: \$I_x=\frac{R_1I_x+V_1}{R_2}\$. Solving for \$I_{sc}\$ gives \$I_{sc}=\frac{V_1}{R_2-R_1}=6\;mA\$. The Thévenin output resistance is thus \$R_{th}=\frac{V_{th}}{I_{sc}}=500\;\Omega\$.

A quick sim confirms the Thévenin voltage:
[image]

A .TF on a 1-A current source determines the small-signal output resistance \$R_{th}\$:

[image]

The .OUT file says:

***** SMALL SIGNAL DC TRANSFER FUNCTION

```
output_impedance_at_V(2) 5.000000e+002
i1#Input_impedance       5.000000e+002
Transfer_function        5.000000e+002
```

Confirming the 500-\$\Omega\$ results.

The Mathcad file is below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually solve this circuit with Thevenin since it is not-linear, but I could be wrong.

However redrawing your circuit..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWMuF8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can see, since the same current \$I_x\$ must flow through both \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$...

\$V_o = V_1 - I_x * R_1 + I_x * R_2\$

\$V_o = V_1 - I_x * (R_1 - R_2)\$

And also

\$I_x = V_O/R_3\$

Substituting gives us..

\$V_O = V_1 - V_O * (R_1 - R_2)/R_3\$

\$V_O * (1 + (R_1 - R_2)/R_3) = V_1\$

\$V_O = V_1 / (1 + (R_1 - R_2)/R_3)\$

---

If \$R_L = 1k\Omega\$ then

\$V_O = 6 / (1 + (1,000 - 2,000)/1,000)\$

\$V_O = 6 / 2\$

\$V_O = 3V\$

---

Adding a load to the circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fABFSO.png)</sup>

\$I_x = V_O/R_3||R_{LOAD}\$

=>

\$V_O = V_1 - V_O * (R_1 - R_2)/R_3||R_{LOAD}\$

\$V_O * (1 + (R_1 - R_2)/R_3||R_{LOAD}) = V_1\$

\$V_O = V_1 / (1 + (R_1 - R_2)/R_3||R_{LOAD})\$

The following curve shows you the relationship between \$V_O\$ and \$R_{LOAD}\$.

[image]

Obviously that does not answer your question as asked..

But you can backtrack the above to get \$I_x\$ from

\$I_x = V_O/R_3||R_{LOAD}\$

So \$V_{R1} = V_O* R_1/R_3||R_{LOAD}\$

Comment: The same circuit https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349731/calculate-vth-in-thevenins-circuit/349748#349748

Comment: @G36 I knew it was familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simpler is better:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftlqEq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

looking at the left hand side of the schematic one KCL at node A followed by an Ohm's law

$$R_\mathrm{eq}=-\frac{V_\mathrm{ab}}{I_\mathrm{x}}=-\frac{1\,\mathrm{k}\Omega\times I_\mathrm{x}}{I_\mathrm{x}}=-1\,\mathrm{k}\Omega$$

thevenizes down to one (negative) resistor.

---

Putting this back into the whole...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcz9ps.png)</sup>

It comes straight forward that

$$R_\mathrm{s}=R_\mathrm{eq}+R_2=-1\,\mathrm{k}\Omega+2\,\mathrm{k}\Omega=1\,\mathrm{k}\Omega$$

and then

$$R_\mathrm{th}=R_\mathrm{s}||R_3=1\,\mathrm{k}\Omega || 1\,\mathrm{k}\Omega=500\,\Omega$$

$$V_\mathrm{th}=V_1\,\frac{R_3}{R_3+R_\mathrm{s}}=6\,\mathrm{V}\times\frac{1\,\mathrm{k}\Omega}{1\,\mathrm{k}\Omega+1\,\mathrm{k}\Omega}=3\,\mathrm{V}$$